# Determine the range of $f(x) = \frac{1}{4}$arccot$(x^2 - 1 ) + \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to determine the range of the function $f(x) = 1/4$ arccot$(x^2 - 1 ) + \frac{\pi}{4}$. I'm a little bit lost, because I thought that because the range of arccot$(x)$ is $]0,\pi[$, then the range of $f$ has to be $]\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}[$. Unfortunately, it seems that the range is $]\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{16}[$. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the $(x^2-1)$ part of the argument in the $arccot$ ?

Comment: Oh, typo, I'll edit!

Comment: The minimal value of $x^2 - 1$ is $-1$  So, the largest value of $\cot^{-1} (x^2 - 1)$ is $\frac {3\pi}{4}$

Comment: What is your background? Do you know calculus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the function is even, that is $f(-x) = f(x)$, so you can restrict yourself to the interval $x \geq 0$. Further, in this interval it is decreasing, because $\cot^{-1}$ is a decreasing function, and multiplication by a positive factor doesn't change this feature of $f$. Neither does addition of a positive number. Hence, the maximum is reached when $x = 0$, that is 
$$f(0) = \frac{1}{4}\cot^{-1}(-1)+\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{3\pi}{16}+\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{7\pi}{16}.$$
There is no minimum instead, as $\cot^{-1}$ doesn't admit a minimum, but you can get $\inf(f(\mathbb{R}))$ computing the limit 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x) = 0+\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$